# Which .net technology to choose when integrating RFID?

Tags: .net, asp.net, rfid

I have a RFID reader which reads my employee code. Now i want to log the date and time of the chip when it is scanned by the reader (ie) for an attendance system Login time and logoff time. I would like to use asp.net MVC and sql server 2005. Any suggestion how to integrate RFID with an asp.net mvc web application. Where should i start?

**EDIT:**

Any other .net technology that can make my job easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at the documentation, provided with the reader, if they have a documented API.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with GvS. I have worked with PSION and Impinj SDKs. PSION was on a mobile platform and more lightweight so you would timestamp to your storage system when the tag was scanned, but with Impinj you can tell the reader to send reports with timestamp of the last time the tag was seen.